# Update pandas dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes.

df1 is

```
     name     colour    count
0    apple    red       3
1    orange   orange    2
3    kiwi     green     12
```

df2 is

```
     name    count
0    kiwi   2
1    apple  1
```

I want to update df1 with count from df2 based on name match.
Expected result:

```
     name     colour    count
0    apple    red       1
1    orange   orange    2
3    kiwi     green     2
```

I am using this but the results are incorrect.

```
df3 = df2.combine_first(df1).reindex(df1.index)
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Is ordering important of `name`s ?

Comment: ordering is not important

Answer (score 2):

Create index by `name` in both `DataFrame`s for matching by them by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) and last [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column from index:

```
df = df2.set_index('name').combine_first(df1.set_index('name')).reset_index()
print (df)
     name  colour  count
0   apple     red    1.0
1    kiwi   green    2.0
2  orange  orange    2.0
```